# Ejecución de jar en Java Web Start

Tags: java

Tengo generado un jar de un sistema desarrollado en Java. Sigo todos los pasos para poder correrlo desde Java Web Start, alojado en un servidor Web. Pasa lo siguiente, luego de realizar la firma correspondiente y todos los pasos previos, accedo al servidor desde mi pc, pidiendo ejecutar el jar. Lo hace sin problemas, abre la ventana de Login, pero al introducir los datos e intentar loguearme a la base de datos me aparece la excepción ClassNotFoundException, ya que no encuentra el driver para la BD. Este problema no me genera localmente, corriendo el jar fuera del entorno web. Alguien sabe porque será?

Comment: Posiblemente en tu entorno local desde consola estés corriendo con el classpath que usas en desarrollo, pero al ejecutarlo desde el jnlp, esas dependencias no estén. Te recomendaría 1) indicar en tu pregunta cómo está hecho el jnlp, 2) revisar el contenido del jar (es un zip, revisa que en lib esté el driver), 3) leer sobre cómo construir un [fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar).

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente todas tus librerías las tienes en local pero cuando exportas el jar no estas incluyendo las librerías necesarias en el mismo jar, por lo tanto, al ejecutarse no las encuentra.

Comment: En realidad si exporta con la librería de jar. Porque el correrlo en el servidor desde la línea de comando lo hace sin problemas. El problema se da cuando quiero ejecutarlos directamente abriendolo con Java, o bien, desde mi pc remota con Java Web Start